# Why does my ejs template crash when I embed a 'require' statement?

Tags: javascript, ejs, selinux

The below .ejs page works perfectly, as shown:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>EJS Test</title>
  <% var greeting = "Hello, world!" %>
  <%# var fs = require("fs") %>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Greeting: <%= greeting %></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

However, when I uncomment the line that requires the fs module, things suddenly fall apart and I only get a totally blank page.  I have tried supplying an absolute path for the 'require' statement.

Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?  Please be aware that SELinux is active on the system.  I don't see anything to indicate that this problem is caused by SELinux; but, I could be missing something.  (It sure seems like it COULD be an SELinux issue that I am just not recognizing.)  Anyway, any assistance in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
   ...doug
```

Comment: `things suddenly fall apart` - what does your browsers developer tools console say - because that page exactly as you've posted it will produce errors because `require` isn't defined in a browser

Comment: My browser developer tools console shows no errors.  I know that 'require' is not defined in a browser.  It is, however, defined in node.js.  So, I would expect that inside <% %> the node.js 'require' would be executed.  I was sure that I have done this many times in the past with no problem.  That's why I wasn't discounting the possibility that it might be an SELinux issue.  Thanks.

Comment: oh, sorry, yes, I didn't even notice the <%